# css !important doesn't work & inline-block changes to block

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is a duplicate post. I hadn't found the answer yet in a few similar posts.

This is my website's HTML:

```css
.navbar-block{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" style="background-color: #393939; position: relative; top: -8px; left: -8px; width: 100%; height: 37px; border: 8px solid #393939;">
    <div id="logo-container" class="navbar-block">
        <a href="/questions" style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
            <p style="font-size: 25px; color: #B8A184;" class="no-select">JFJudge</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-question" class="no-select navbar-block"><p style="font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; transform: translateY(-1px);">Questions</p></div>
</div>
```

However, the styles `inline-block` `margin-left` `margin-right` all don't seem to work. I checked the display style of the element using a console script. It seems like it has the `block` style instead.

The solution was to put inline CSS in the element `logo-container` and `navbar-question`.

I'm trying to solve the problem by only editing the CSS stylesheet. I also tried:

```css
.navbar-block{
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    margin-right: 5px !important;
}
```

It still doesn't work.

Anything I should try now? Thank you.

Note: I'm using Django localhost to test the HTML, and the stylesheet is put in the static folder.

Comment: No problem in theory, write an online demo please!

Comment: if everything is right, then they must be overwritten by other css styles, or it's probably the css stylesheet file failed to load

Comment: @QiuZhou I can tell that the stylesheet loads successfully, since other css script written in the file does make changes to other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably another line overwriting your important line. What I always do in these cases is: open the page in firefox, right-click on the concerned element and click on "investigate" to open the dev tool, then normally your overwritten css line will have a filter displayed next to it. click on that icon, and it will exactly show you which css line overwrites the existing one.

Comment: Ahh shoot, I forgot to run `python manage.py collectstatic` in Django. Thank you for providing this method!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a JS function running onLoad that changed the display... I can not believe we can have answers to such weird questions in SO :)