# I want to stretch a logo's width and fix the size of logo so that it is clearly visible

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

The selected logo should be visible enough.I have added media queries but not able to work it properly.The logo can be stretched width wise,but I don't know how to do that.
[image]

As of now I have done

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <h3 class="eta m-0">Estimated Delivery Date</h3><br>
    <h1 class="textFontAndColor">Friday 29, September</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/united-states-postal-service.svg" class="fill"><br>
    <span class="textFontAndColor">EZ00093838993N</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please, add the CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

The image file itself has quite a lot of whitespace around it so if possible maybe using a wrapper div to crop it would help the situation.

The styling here might not work right away, but just by eyeballing I was able to throw something together that at least for me locally worked well enough.

```
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img class="logo" alt="" src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/united-states-postal-service.svg" class="fill">
   </div>
</div>

.imgWrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -300px;
}
```

So the `imgWrapper`s width and height controls the overall viewpoint thats to be shown and with `logo`s width and height you can fix the logo image to be proper size and playing with margins get the position right.

Answer (score -1):

you're using an incorrect media query syntax; the syntax for media queries is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  selector {
    property: value;
  }
}
```

You may also simply provide the image with a unique class name, to avoid unnecessary complicated css selectors as the one you're using.

Comment: This is what I have used `@media (min-width: 768px){
    .fill{
        max-height: 3rem;
        position: relative;
    }
  }`

Comment: in your dev-tool screenshot the outter braces are missing. If you corrected that and it's still not working, this means that your css rule is overwritten by another styling rule. In this case, please refer to my answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702677/css-important-doesnt-work-inline-block-changes-to-block/63702830#63702830

Comment: Ohk..Could you pls help me to solve the problem now?

Comment: I answered to your question with my commetn above..?

Comment: When you inspect your img element in the firefox browser, what do you get for its css rules, are they lined through, meaning that they're overwritten, or active? Also, I hope that it wasn't you who downvoted my answer, because your media query was indeed wrong coded according to your screenshot..

Comment: No it was not me who downvoted your answer.But still I did not find any specific answer to my question

Comment: pretty annoying such downvotes, anyway. Did you do what I wrote above? like this we can find out if it's not working because your CSS rule got overridden. Please follow the instructions of the link I copied in my second comment to my answer above, and check if this works..